# Find specific rows and cells in Excel calendar based on current date

Tags: excel, vba

With zero luck finding a solution on the web I was wondering if anyone here can help me. Below is an example of my calendar.

[image: Calendar]

Above is my calendar with Month, weeknumber and days at the very top. At the very left there are names. I am trying to get the names of the persons who have F in cell of current day (if April the 13th was today). The days has DD.MM.YYYY Format.

Explained in details:
I'm looking for a code that finds todays date in row 3. when that date is found find all cells in column W which contains "F". Then I want the name of the person in that row.

And finally a bad illustrated image of what I'm thinking.

[image]

The output should look something like this. All the names should not be listed in one cell.

[image: output]

Hope for some help!

Comment: And how do you want the output? In a list? In a single cell?  Please mock up how the output should look.

Comment: I just need the output to be the name. in this example: The value of D5,D8 and D13 (Name1,Name4, Name9) And it should be in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Row 3 has dates like DD/MM/YYYY but you changed the format to Custom and only included DD, then the following will work:

```
Sub foo()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim NextEmptyRow As Long
Dim SearchDate As String

LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
'SearchDate = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
'change the line below with the one above to search for today's date
SearchDate = "13/04/2017" 'find "today's" date
LastCol = Sheet1.Cells(3, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'get the last Column
Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Output"
For i = 1 To LastCol 'loop through all columns
ValueToFind = Format(Sheet1.Cells(3, i).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") 'format the values on row 3 to full date as dd/mm/yyy
    If ValueToFind = SearchDate Then 'if date on Row 3 matches SearchDate then
        For x = 4 To LastRow 'loop through rows
            If Sheet1.Cells(x, i).Value = "F" Then 'if F exists on that column
                NextEmptyRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'check the next free row on Sheet 2 column A
                Sheet2.Cells(NextEmptyRow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, 4).Value 'copy the name to Sheet2 on the next available Row
            End If
        Next x
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure this out! Because i had some extra cells in my project that i forgot to show in the above example. But i finally figured it out. Ended with editing LastCol from 3 to 16 and that fixed my problem.
Thanks alot!